# Web-based Alexa skill receives both IntentRequest and SessionEndedRequest simultaneously

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I have already written one skill that works wonderfully, but this second one is not cooperating. It is a simple trivia-like skill (you can see the ​[code on GitHub](https://github.com/jakerella/alexa-bridge-keeper)) and the launch and initial intent work well. When the skill asks the user a question and waits for an answer, however, my server receives two HTTP requests, one for the `IntentRequest` (the user's answer) and one for a `SessionEndedRequest`. Amazon is ignoring my response to the IntentRequest (which is working independently) because it has already sent a SessionEndedRequest.

I have tested this skill in the "Service Simulator" on Amazon, with ​[Echosim](https://echosim.io/), and on my own Echo device. In the Service Simulator everything works fine - my guess is because it only sends a single request to my server. (That's how I know my code handles the IntentRequest for the user's answer just fine.) However, when I test on Echosim or on my own device I receive two requests at the same time: the intent and the session ending:

```
2016-07-30T21:47:30.819563+00:00 app[web.1]:  { version: '1.0',
2016-07-30T21:47:30.819564+00:00 app[web.1]:   session:
2016-07-30T21:47:30.819565+00:00 app[web.1]:    { new: false,
2016-07-30T21:47:30.819566+00:00 app[web.1]:      sessionId: 'amzn1.echo-api.session.e42282ad-c89f-4bb9-b434-259686f26b47',
2016-07-30T21:47:30.819567+00:00 app[web.1]:      application: { applicationId: 'amzn1.ask.skill....' },
2016-07-30T21:47:30.819567+00:00 app[web.1]:      attributes: { question: 'name' },
2016-07-30T21:47:30.819573+00:00 app[web.1]:      user: { userId: 'amzn1.ask.account....' } },
2016-07-30T21:47:30.819574+00:00 app[web.1]:   request:
2016-07-30T21:47:30.819575+00:00 app[web.1]:    { type: 'IntentRequest',
2016-07-30T21:47:30.819575+00:00 app[web.1]:      requestId: 'amzn1.echo-api.request.a9991397-11a8-4fac-8406-33fb1b419b62',
2016-07-30T21:47:30.819576+00:00 app[web.1]:      timestamp: '2016-07-30T21:47:30Z',
2016-07-30T21:47:30.819576+00:00 app[web.1]:      locale: 'en-US',
2016-07-30T21:47:30.819577+00:00 app[web.1]:      intent: { name: 'GiveAnswer', slots: [Object] } } }
2016-07-30T21:47:30.819710+00:00 app[web.1]: Did they answer correctly? name king arthur
2016-07-30T21:47:30.847813+00:00 app[web.1]: New request for the bridge keeper:
2016-07-30T21:47:30.847815+00:00 app[web.1]:  { version: '1.0',
2016-07-30T21:47:30.847816+00:00 app[web.1]:   session:
2016-07-30T21:47:30.847816+00:00 app[web.1]:    { new: false,
2016-07-30T21:47:30.847817+00:00 app[web.1]:      sessionId: 'amzn1.echo-api.session.e42282ad-c89f-4bb9-b434-259686f26b47',
2016-07-30T21:47:30.847818+00:00 app[web.1]:      application: { applicationId: 'amzn1.ask.skill....' },
2016-07-30T21:47:30.847818+00:00 app[web.1]:      attributes: { question: 'name' },
2016-07-30T21:47:30.847819+00:00 app[web.1]:      user: { userId: 'amzn1.ask.account....' } },
2016-07-30T21:47:30.847820+00:00 app[web.1]:   request:
2016-07-30T21:47:30.847820+00:00 app[web.1]:    { type: 'SessionEndedRequest',
2016-07-30T21:47:30.847821+00:00 app[web.1]:      requestId: 'amzn1.echo-api.request.f2497e02-9ef4-405e-aee0-c7d2b6c67622',
2016-07-30T21:47:30.847821+00:00 app[web.1]:      timestamp: '2016-07-30T21:47:30Z',
2016-07-30T21:47:30.847822+00:00 app[web.1]:      locale: 'en-US',
2016-07-30T21:47:30.847822+00:00 app[web.1]:      reason: 'ERROR' } }
```

Above you can see the body of both requests and the times... nearly simultaneous. If Amazon were to NOT send that SessionEndedRequest my skill would have worked fine!

Has anyone seen this before? Any thoughts on what is going on?